# Comparision of two list object for equality not giving proper result

Tags: c#, collections

I tried three ways of comparing two lists but not a single way is working.

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list1 = new List<A>()
            {
                {new A(){Id = Guid.Parse("1BA3B3A3-FD4C-E311-B616-A41F729385FA")}},
                {new A(){Id = Guid.Parse("90DF3989-16FC-4E2B-A0C7-A3640156D6F2")}}
            };



        var list2 = new List<A>()
            {
                {new A(){Id = Guid.Parse("1BA3B3A3-FD4C-E311-B616-A41F729385FA")}},
                {new A(){Id = Guid.Parse("90DF3989-16FC-4E2B-A0C7-A3640156D6F2")}}
            };

        var test1 = ListEuality<A>(list1, list2, );
        var areEquivalent = (list1.Count == list2.Count) && !list1.Except(list2).Any();

        var test = list1.OrderBy(t => t.Id).SequenceEqual(list2.OrderBy(t => t.Id));



        Console.ReadLine();

    }
//This Method compares two lists for equality without taking consideration of order.
    public static bool ListEuality<T>(IEnumerable<T> list1, IEnumerable<T> list2)
    {
        var cnt = new Dictionary<T, int>(comparer);
        foreach (T s in list1)
        {
            if (cnt.ContainsKey(s))
            {
                cnt[s]++;
            }
            else
            {
                cnt.Add(s, 1);
            }
        }
        foreach (T s in list2)
        {
            if (cnt.ContainsKey(s))
            {
                cnt[s]--;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

//If dictionary element becomes 0 means dictionary modified for each item that means items are present in both list
            return cnt.Values.All(c => c == 0);
        }

```
class A
{
    public Guid Id;
}
```

Comment: My Bad!! Its just a silly mistake. I have created new instance of A each time. I should have created new instance and saved in some variable and then assigned same variables to different lists. Sorry for silly mistake. I am not deleting my question. It may help someone.

Answer (score 1):

Probably all you need to do is to override the `Equals` method for your `A` object like so:

```
public override bool Equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) return false;
    A objA = obj as A;
    if (objA == null) return false;
    return (this.Id.Equals(objA.Id));
}
```

This code:

```
void Main()
{
    Guid g = Guid.Parse("1BA3B3A3-FD4C-E311-B616-A41F729385FA");
    A a = new A();
    a.Id = g;
    Guid h = Guid.Parse("1BA3B3A3-FD4C-E311-B616-A41F729385FA");
    A b = new A();
    b.Id = h;

    bool eq = a.Equals(b);

    Console.WriteLine(eq);
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class A {
    public Guid Id;

    public override bool Equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) return false;
        A objA = obj as A;
        if (objA == null) return false;
        return (this.Id.Equals(objA.Id));
    }
}
```

If you override `Equals`, it returns `True`. If you remove the `Equals` method for the A-class, it returns `False`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you are using different instances of A. A way to do it without overriding comparison for A would be

```
bool areEquivalent = (list1.Count == list2.Count) && !list1.Select(a => a.ID).Except(list2.Select(a => a.ID).Any();
```

Meaning you only compare the GUIDs